# Pythonic way to refer to files, paths, and full file paths?

Tags: python

Looking for a clear way to name my variables. Below is an example of the values they will store.

```
'IMG_5123.JPG'
'/path/to/IMG_5123.JPG'
'/path/to/'
 'JPG'
```

I was thinking filename, filename_full, path, extension. Is there a "proper" way to name these items?

Comment: Those variable names sound good to me. Just make sure you include the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my perspective and you can of course select any scheme that you want.

Because they all represent parts of the same filename, I would prefix them all with "filename" or "fn" (if it's really clear what it means). Therefore: filename, filename_abs, filename_path, filename_ext or a similar set.

If they are going to represent images specifically I would probably modify that.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables look ok to me. If you need additional inspiration you can check the std lib ofr os.path that's dealing with a lot of these concepts: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 1):

you should read [pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) to learn proper styling in python.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix and Unix-like operating systems you have the dirname and basename commands. If you use their widely used nomenclature then:

```
file basename: 'IMG_5123.JPG'
file name:     '/path/to/IMG_5123.JPG'
file dirname:  '/path/to/'
file suffix:   'JPG'
```

But nothing is ever that neat. The basename is also called the filename; the name is also called the full pathname; the dirname is often called the path, and the suffix is often called the extension.